# How to increase rows in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *categoryStr = categoryName.text;
NSLog(@"Category Name:--->%@",categoryStr);

appDelegate.categoryData = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
categoryStr, @"name",image ,@"image", nil] mutableCopy];

[appDelegate.categories addObject:appDelegate.categoryData];
NSLog(@"Category Data:--->%@",appDelegate.categories);
```

My problem is that every time I got only one rows means appDelegate.categories returns 1 row but I want to increment appDelegate.categories (NSMutableArray).

Comment: Where do you create `appDelegate.categories`, it seems you are creating every time this code is executed.

Comment: I am create appDelegate.categories in appDelegate.m file plz help

Comment: why u do like this. just create an mutable array and add objects in this array

Comment: I want to add rows dynamically in nsmutablearray

Comment: Any idea because I want to use appdelegate array in another class???

Comment: u just add object an array it's work try it

Answer (score 0):

`addObject` adds a new entry to the array.  If you're always getting only one entry it's because you keep reallocating the array vs using the old one.

Comment: Yes. It adds as separate items. I thought the problem could be something related to it.